# MySQL move data from one table to another, matching ID's

Tags: mysql, sql

I have (a.o.) two MySQL tables with (a.o.) the following columns:

```
tweets:
-------------------------------------
id text        from_user_id from_user
-------------------------------------
1  Cool tweet! 13295354     tradeny
2  Tweeeeeeeet 43232544     bolleke
3  Yet another 13295354     tradeny
4  Something.. 53546443     janusz4

users:
-------------------------------------
id from_user num_tweets from_user_id
-------------------------------------
1  tradeny   2235
2  bolleke   432
3  janusz4   5354
```

I now want to normalize the tweets table, replacing tweets.from_user with an integer that matches users.id. Secondly, I want to fill in the corresponding users.from_user_id, Finally, I want to delete tweets.from_user_id so that the end result would look like:

```
tweets:
------------------------
id text        from_user
------------------------
1  Cool tweet!     1
2  Tweeeeeeeet     2
3  Yet another     1
4  Something..     3

users:
-------------------------------------
id from_user num_tweets from_user_id
-------------------------------------
1  tradeny   2235       13295354
2  bolleke   432        43232544
3  janusz4   5354       53546443
```

My question is whether one could help me form the proper queries for this. I have only come so far:

```
UPDATE tweets SET from_user =
  (SELECT id FROM users WHERE from_user = tweets.from_user)
WHERE...

UPDATE users SET from_user_id =
  (SELECT from_user_id FROM tweets WHERE from_user = tweets.from_user)
WHERE...

ALTER TABLE tweets DROP from_user_id
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

Example Work:

**Tweet Table**

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2144/mysql-move-data-from-one-table-to-another-matching-ids

**Users Table**

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qe/2145/mysql-move-data-from-one-table-to-another-matching-ids

```
UPDATE users
SET users.from_user_id = tweets.from_user_id
FROM users
LEFT JOIN tweets ON users.from_user = tweets.from_user;

UPDATE tweets
SET tweets.from_user = users.id
FROM tweets
LEFT JOIN users ON tweets.from_user = users.from_user;

ALTER TABLE tweets DROP COLUMN from_user_id;
ALTER TABLE tweets ALTER COLUMN from_user int;
```

##Possible MySQL Query##
**NOT TESTED**

```
UPDATE users, tweets
SET users.from_user_id = tweets.from_user_id
WHERE users.from_user = tweets.from_user;

UPDATE tweets, users
SET tweets.from_user = users.id
WHERE tweets.from_user = users.from_user;

ALTER TABLE tweets DROP COLUMN from_user_id;
ALTER TABLE tweets CHANGE COLUMN from_user from_user int;
```

Comment: Both "UPDATE tweets SET tweets.from_user = users.uid FROM tweets LEFT JOIN users ON tweets.from_user = users.screen_name" as "UPDATE FROM tweets LEFT JOIN users ON tweets.from_user = users.screen_name SET tweets.from_user = users.uid" return an error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM' [...]". I have checked, but I believe both queries to be of correct syntax and "tweets" is not a reserved word...any ideas?

Comment: Also, thanks on the example work; hadn't seen this Stack Overflow feature yet :-) Do you always name table names like "#name"? (with hash)

Comment: i don't have mysql access at the moment, when i have i will check these queries for mysql, #name is temporary table @data.stackexchange you need to create temporary tables to try queries

Comment: Added possible mysql query from mysql reference **need test**

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

```
UPDATE FROM tweets t 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.from_user = t.from_user
SET t.from_user = u.id

UPDATE FROM users u
LEFT JOIN tweets t ON t.from_user = u.from_user
SET u.from_user_id = t.from_user_id

ALTER TABLE tweets DROP COLUMN from_user_id
```